# Why does this JPA code not update entity in AppEngine local datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

So I have the follow entity with the following code to create and update the object. The resulting data after calling the method is that the field `Value` has the value of `1` in the Datastore running at my local computer. Why? Isn't the object JPA-managed (or *attached* as described in [this article](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/ejb/ejb3_manipulating.htm)) and supposed to update itself upon `em2.close()`?

**Entity:**

```
@Entity 
public class MyObj {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long Id;
    public int Value = 0;
}
```

**Code:**

```
public void createAndUpdate() {
    Long id = null;
    // Line below calls Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional").createEntityManager()
    EntityManager em1 = Database.getEntityManager(); 
    MyObj obj = new MyObj();
    obj.Value = 1;      
    em1.persist(obj);
    em1.close();
    id = obj.Id;

    EntityManager em2 = Database.getEntityManager();
    obj = (MyObj) em2.find(MyObj.class, id);
    obj.Value = 2;
    // NOTE1
    em2.close();        
}
```

On the line marked `NOTE1` I have tried inserting  `em2.persist(obj)` and `em2.merge(obj)` (even though from what I've read, that should not be neccessary since `find()` returns an *attached* object). None of them helped.

I'm using JPA v1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the JPA spec says, **you cannot directly update fields of Entity objects**, yet in your posted code you do just that (so the persistence provider has no way of knowing that something has changed, and so can't flush those changes to the datastore).

[DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform.html) does actually allow you to update the field directly **if you enhance the class that does it to be "PersistenceAware".**

Solution : use setters to update fields

Comment: So you're saying the spec says you cannot use fields, but Datanucleus implemented it anyway? @PersistenceAware did it for me so I will go for that solution instead of getter/setters. Thanks!